# How to change the shell title in Fiori App

Tags: sapui5

I am looking at changing the ShellAppTitle in a Fiori app. Refer the highlighted part in the snapshot below:
[image: App shell title]

I already know a way to to this which I am not proud of:

> sap.ui.getCore().byId("shellAppTitle").getText() /.setText()

Is there any better approach to achieve this?

Comment: You shouldn't do that. The `appTitle` is used for the Fiori Launchpad tiles and the shell title. The titles should be the same. There's no reason to change the title.

Answer (score 3):

The only improvement I could think of is to implement this via the FLP ShellUIService rather than the `getCore()` method. The reason being that if SAP changes the id of the header text, your code will break since it is not designed to work this way.

To implement the service, first declare it in your `manifest.json`:

```
{
...
"sap.ui5": {
  "services" : {
     "ShellUIService": {
         "factoryName": "sap.ushell.ui5service.ShellUIService"
     }
  }
}
...
}
```

Then, you can access it in your `Component.js` via the following code:

```
// Component.js (the app root component)
...
this.getService("ShellUIService").then( // promise is returned
  function (oService) {
    oService.setTitle("Application Title"); // also could use .getTitle() first
  },
  function (oError) {
    jQuery.sap.log.error("Cannot get ShellUIService", oError, "my.app.Component");
  }
);
...
```

The full documentation can be found in the [SAPUI5 SDK](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ushell.ui5service.ShellUIService/constructor)